# Can I use drake to test Visual SLAM algorithms?

Tags: drake

I was wondering whether I could leverage the modularity drake gives to test Visual SLAM algorithms on realtime data. I would like to create 3 blocks that output acceleration, angular speed, and RGBD data. The blocks should pull information from a real sensor. Another block would process the data and produce the current transform of the camera and a global map. Effectively, I would like to cast my problem into a "Systems" framework so I can easily add filters where I need them.

My question is: Given other people's experience with this library, is Drake the right tool for the job for this usecase? Specifically, can I use this library to process real time information in a production setting?

Answer (score 1):

Visual SLAM is not a use case I've implemented myself, but I believe the Drake Systems framework should be up to the task, depending on what you mean by "realtime".

We definitely ship RGBD data through the framework often.

We haven't made any attempt to support running Drake in hard realtime, but certainly can run at high rates.  If you were to hit a performance bottleneck, we tend to be pretty responsive and would welcome PRs.

As for the "production-level", it is certainly our intention for the code / process to be mature enough for that setting, and numerous teams do already.

Comment: @jc211 Wikipedia's definitions of different degrees of real-time may also help you choose what you're OK with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing